# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to run my example which include hibernate3 annotation and Spring but when I am deploying my project it throws this error. Please suggest me where and how to map this xml file.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1282)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1380)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1385)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1649)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1638)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
        ... 23 more
    May 2, 2014 6:17:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: Post your web.xml file.

Comment: These are new tags under default web.xml i have added           <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 
 
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

Answer (score 2):

Try to put **applicationContext.xml** in the **src/main/resources** folder and just give *"applicationContext.xml"* as the reference, not *"src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml"*.

If that doesn't work, archive your project, post it somewhere we can download it so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Sir, please tell me site for uploading my project

Comment: If you have a Dropbox account, you can generate a publicly-accesible link (see https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en for instructions)

Comment: ok, i m checking till please check this link to take a look of my simple project                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440573/caused-by-java-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-open-servletcontext-resource