# Spring java based configuration - Could not open ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using full java based configuration for a project.

When deploying webapp, I get the following error :

> Sep 06, 2016 8:13:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   Sep 06, 2016 8:13:37 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
>   INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
>   Sep 06, 2016 8:13:37 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 06 08:13:37 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   Sep 06, 2016 8:13:38 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/net.brewspberry.util.SpringWebappConfiguration]
>   Sep 06, 2016 8:13:38 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
>   SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/net.brewspberry.util.SpringWebappConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/net.brewspberry.util.SpringWebappConfiguration]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/net.brewspberry.util.SpringWebappConfiguration]
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
>       ... 21 more

The thing is I don't get why Spring tries to load an XML config while I registered a Class config :

WebappInitializer :

```
package net.brewspberry.util.config;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import net.brewspberry.filters.AuthentificationFilter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringWebappInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements
        WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

        // rootContext.setConfigLocation("net.brewspberry.util");

        rootContext.register(SpringCoreConfiguration.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // now the config for the Dispatcher servlet
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new     AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    // mvcContext.setConfigLocation("net.brewspberry.util.config");
    //mvcContext.register(SpringWebappConfiguration.class);


    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
            "DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));

    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("*.do");

}




@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return null; // new Filter[] { new AuthentificationFilter() };

}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Webapp config :

```
package net.brewspberry.util.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "net.brewspberry" })
public class SpringWebappConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/login.jsp");
    }

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

I have no web.xml necesary as WebAppInitializer replaces it. I tried with or without that line :

```
        mvcContext.register(SpringWebappConfiguration.class);
```

but it does not change anything.

Moreover, in logs, Spring searches for XML application context while in initializer it is defined as an annotation application context. I don't get it...

Any idea ?

Comment: `[/net.brewspberry.util.SpringWebappConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource ` Are you sure about path??...check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440573/caused-by-java-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-open-servletcontext-resource

Comment: Also please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350721/could-not-open-servletcontext-resource-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify dispatcher servlet to use SpringWebappConfiguration as it context or set SpringWebappConfiguration as applicationRoot context.